# Finding a set of all pair-wise ORs of two sets of integers

Tags: algorithm, set

Given two sets, each containing integer values, how could one find a set containing all possible pair-wise `ORs` of the values of those two sets? E.g. (all numbers are binary)

```
{1, 10} x {100, 1000} = {101, 1001, 110, 1010}
{1, 10} x {11, 101} = {11, 101, 111}
```

The first example results in full four combinations, while the second one only results in three, since both sets share some bits. Obviously the result can be calculated in `O(m*n)`, but is there a faster way of solving this, taking into account that in many cases the size of the result would be less than `m*n`?

In some of the cases the resulting set is significantly smaller than `m*n` (e.g. `{1, 11, 111} x {10, 110} = {11, 111}`) - but I can't quite pinpoint the exact nature of all those cases in a generic-enough way to get an algorithm. Ideally it should run in `O(r)`, where `r` is the size of the resulting set. There may be some way to partition source sets, build-up the result using a dynamic programming approach, or do something else in that vein, but for now I can't find it.

Comment: That doesn't make a lot of sense. `m*n` is the worst case, so what kinds of cases do you want to optimize? Do you want an "output-sensitive" algorithm that only takes as much time as the result is large? How many bits are there? Because there is an obvious `2^k` upper bound for the result of sets with numbers `< 2^k`

Comment: Exactly - an algorithm that only takes as much time as the result is large. For example, in some cases (e.g. `{1, 11, 111} x {10, 110}`) the output is no larger than one of the sets - it feels that in such cases the result could be found in less than `m*n`.

Comment: Would a `2^k` algorithm be useful? What is the range of your numbers

Comment: `k` is supposed to be 32 or 64 (reflecting the underlying storage type), so a `2^k` algorithm might not be practical.

Comment: I think it's likely that the naive O(m*n) solution is the route you'll have to take. There's no way in the general case to know beforehand whether `x<n>|y<m>` matches an element already produced without checking it, unless there are some specific symmetries in your input sets that you can exploit.

Comment: Your example `{1, 11, 111} x {10, 110} = {1, 11, 111}` seems incorrect. Shouldn't the result be `{11, 111}`?

Comment: @twalberg: Do you have a proof of that? From my intuition it's well possible that there is an algorithm that solves this problem in the output size times plus maybe some kind of polylogarithmic factor.

Comment: @NiklasB.No, no proof... Just my impression based on the idea that I don't think you can tell if a pair you haven't considered yet will yield a duplicate of one you've already seen, without trying it. And the only way to consider all pairs is to walk through all m*n of them...

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know much about it, I wonder if, depending on the cardinality of the data, using a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) for one set could improve efficiency. When traversing the other set to `or` with the indexed set, whole branches of the tree may be skipped if it can be determined that bits are matched for the current integer in the indexed set.

Another optimization could be to skip all pairings of bit-length n if we already have 2^(n-1) results of that length; for example, there are eight possible integers, four bits in length.