# How to return Haskell subtries containing keys not beginning with a prefix

Tags: haskell, trie

I've been toying around with the Haskell Data.Trie module in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234322/finding-a-set-of-all-pair-wise-ors-of-two-sets-of-integers) and was wondering if someone might know/suggest of a way to return, rather than the matching submap, the subtries that do not match a prefix. In the example below, for `[0,1]`, I would want `[1,1]` and `[1,0,1]`; and for `[1]`, null.

What I thought about was probably not as efficient as I would like - something like looking for keys that do not intersect with the regular subtrie.

```
Prelude Data.Trie...> let t=Data.Trie.fromList [(pack [1,1],3),(pack [1,0,1],5)]

Prelude Data.Trie...> Data.Trie.submap (pack [0,1]) t
Data.Trie.fromList []

Prelude Data.Trie...> Data.Trie.submap (pack [1]) t
Data.Trie.fromList [("\SOH\NUL\SOH",5),("\SOH\SOH",3)]
```

Comment: I guess this won't be easy as the library doesn't expose any internals that could be used to create such a new, low-level function. Probably the most reasonable choice would be to study the internals and contribute such a function to the library. | Or, you could roll your own trie implementation. Since it seems that your keys are just booleans, this shouldn't be difficult and it looks like a nice exercise.